# Show filterrific form in different controller view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, filterrific

I want to show the filterrific form in landing page of my application. How do I make the form respond to different controller action?

The code below is from Filterrific Sample Application. I want to search and filter the Student Model. And I want users of my application to be able to search the students from Home page of Welcome Controller.

```html
<%# app/views/students/index.html.erb %>
<h1>Students</h1>

    <%= form_for_filterrific @filterrific do |f| %>
  <div>
    Search
    <%# give the search field the 'filterrific-periodically-observed' class for live updates %>
    <%= f.text_field(
      :search_query,
      class: 'filterrific-periodically-observed'
    ) %>
  </div>
  <div>
    Country
    <%= f.select(
      :with_country_id,
      @filterrific.select_options[:with_country_id],
      { include_blank: '- Any -' }
    ) %>
  </div>
  <div>
    Registered after
    <%= f.text_field(:with_created_at_gte, class: 'js-datepicker') %>
  </div>
  <div>
    Sorted by
    <%= f.select(:sorted_by, @filterrific.select_options[:sorted_by]) %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= link_to(
      'Reset filters',
      reset_filterrific_url,
    ) %>
  </div>
  <%# add an automated spinner to your form when the list is refreshed %>
  <%= render_filterrific_spinner %>
<% end %>

<%= render(
  partial: 'students/list',
  locals: { students: @students }
) %>
```

This code works because I have filterrific setup from index.html page of Students Controller. I want to show this form in Home page of my Welcome Controller so that when users put their filter criteria and search it will take them to the students index page with their search results. How do I make it work from there? What changes I should make to the form?

Check out this page for the sample application. [Example Filterrific application](http://filterrific.clearcove.ca/)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following for the desired behavior:

- Override the `:url` option on `form_for_filterrific` so that it submits to `StudentsController#index` instead of the home page.
- Turn off ajax auto submit and submit the form manually. Ajax behavior is added based on the form's `id` attr. So the easiest way to turn off Auto ajax submit is to change the id.
- Add a `Submit` button to the form for manual submission.

Here is the relevant code:

```
<%= form_for_filterrific(
      @filterrific, 
      url: students_path, 
      html: { id: :manual_filterrific_form }
    ) do |f| %>
  [form inputs go here ...]
  <%= f.submit "Show students" %>
<% end %>
```

Now the form is displayed on the home page. When a user sets the filters and clicks "Show students", they will be taken to `StudentsController#index` and see the filtered list of students.